# Mongo aggregate nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection with following structure

```js
{
    "userId" : ObjectId("XXX"),
    "itemId" : ObjectId("YYY"),
    "resourceId" : 1,
    "_id" : ObjectId("528455229486ca3606004ec9"),
    "parameter" : [
        {
            "name" : "name1",
            "value" : 150,
            "_id" : ObjectId("528455359486ca3606004eed")
        },
        {
            "name" : "name2",
            "value" : 0,
            "_id" : ObjectId("528455359486ca3606004eec")
        },
        {
            "name" : "name3",
            "value" : 2,
            "_id" : ObjectId("528455359486ca3606004eeb")
        }
    ]
}
```

There can be multiple documents with the same 'useId' with different 'itemId' but the parameter will have same key/value pairs in all of them.

What I am trying to accomplish is return aggregated parameters "name1", "name2" and "name3" for each unique "userId" disregard the 'itemId'. so final results would look like for each user :

```js
{
  "userId" : ObjectId("use1ID"),
  "name1" : (aggregatedValue),
  "name2" : (aggregatedValue),
  "name3" : (aggregatedVAlue) 
},
{
  "userId" : ObjectId("use2ID"),
  "name1" : (aggregatedValue),
  "name2" : (aggregatedValue),
  "name3" : (aggregatedVAlue) 
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish this using the aggregated methods of mongoDB ? Could you please help me to build the proper query to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest form of this is to keep things keyed by the "parameter" "name":

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
   // Unwind the array
   { "$unwind": "$parameter"},

   // Group on the "_id" and "name" and $sum "value"
   { "$group": {
       "_id": { 
           "userId": "$userId",
           "name": "$parameter.name"
       }, 
       "value": { "$sum": "$parameter.value" } 
   }},

   // Put things into an array for "nice" processing
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id.userId",
       "values": { "$push": { 
           "name": "$_id.name",
           "value": "$value"
       }}
   }}
)
```

If you **really** need to have the "values" of names as the field values, you *can* do the the following. But since you are "projecting" the fields/properties then you must specify them all **in your code**. You cannot be "dynamic" anymore and you are *coding/generating* each one:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$parameter"},

   // Group on the "_id" and "name" and $sum "value"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
             "userId": "$userId",
             "name": "$parameter.name"
        },
        "value": { "$sum": "$parameter.value"}
    }},

    // Project out discrete "field" names with $cond
    { "$project": {
        "name1": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$_id.name", "name1" ] },
            "$value",
            0
        ]},
        "name2": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$_id.name", "name2" ] },
            "$value",
            0
        ]},
        "name3": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$_id.name", "name3" ] },
            "$value",
            0
        ]},
    }},

    // The $cond put "0" values in there. So clean up with $group and $sum
    { "$group": { 
        _id: "$_id.userId",
        "name1": { "$sum": "$name1" },
        "name2": { "$sum": "$name2" },
        "name3": { "$sum": "$name3" }
    }}
```

])

So while the extra steps give you the result that you want ( well with a final project to change the `_id` to `userId` ), for my mind the short version is workable enough, unless you really do need it. Consider the output from there as well:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53245016ea402b31d77b0372"),
    "values" : [
        {
            "name" : "name3",
            "value" : 2
        },
        {
            "name" : "name2",
            "value" : 0
        },
        {
            "name" : "name1",
            "value" : 150
        }
    ]
}
```

So that would be what I would use, personally. But your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I got your question but if the name field can contain only `"name1", "name2", "name3"` or at least you are only interested in this values, one of the possible queries could be this one:

```
db.aggTest.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$parameter"}, 
    {$project: {"userId":1, "parameter.name":1, 
       "name1" : {"$cond": [{$eq : ["$parameter.name", "name1"]}, "$parameter.value", 0]},
       "name2" : {"$cond": [{$eq : ["$parameter.name", "name2"]}, "$parameter.value", 0]}, 
       "name3" : {"$cond": [{$eq : ["$parameter.name", "name3"]}, "$parameter.value", 0]}}}, 
    {$group : {_id : {userId:"$userId"}, 
       name1 : {$sum:"$name1"}, 
       name2 : {$sum:"$name2"}, 
       name3 : {$sum:"$name3"}}})
```

It firsts unwinds the parameter array, then separates name1, name2 and name3 values into different columns. There's a simple conditional statement for that. After that we can easily aggreagate by the new columns.

Hope it helps!